Klaviyo integration oauth revoke api
Issue with Revoking Integration via OAuth API
We are attempting to revoke the Klaviyo integration for a user using the /oauth/revoke API. While the API call succeeds with a 200 OK response, the app is not being removed from the "Integrations" page in the user's Klaviyo account.
Here are the specifics:
API Request Details:
Endpoint: https://a.klaviyo.com/oauth/revoke
Token provided: refresh_token (using token_type_hint: refresh_token)
Authorization: Basic header with client credentials
Response:
Status Code: 200
Response Body: {}
Below is the code we are using for this operation
`
let response:any;
const formData = await request.formData();
const requestData: Record<string, string> = {};
formData.forEach((value, key) => {
requestData[key] = String(value);

});
let user = await prisma.user.findFirst({
where:{

    name:requestData.store_name,

    app_name:requestData.app_name,

}

});
if(user){
const accessToken = await refresh_token(user?.id);

const klaviyoClientId = process.env.KLAVIYO_CLIENT_ID;

const klaviyoClientSecret = process.env.KLAVIYO_CLIENT_SECRET;

if(accessToken){

    let data = new URLSearchParams({

        'token_type_hint': 'refresh_token',

        "token": `Bearer ${accessToken}`

    })

    const url = 'https://a.klaviyo.com/oauth/revoke';

    const options = {

        method: 'GET',

        headers: {

            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${klaviyoClientId}:${klaviyoClientSecret}`),

            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

          },

          body:data,

    };

    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    if(!response.ok){

        let response = json({status:'error', msg:'Something went wrong'});

        await cors(request, response); // this mutates the Response object

        return response;

    }

    else{

        let update = prisma.user.update({

            where:{

                id:user.id

            },

            data:{

                api_token:null,

            }

        })

        let response = json({status:'success', msg:'App disconnected successfully'});

        await cors(request, response); // this mutates the Response object

        return response;

    }

}

else{

    return "abc";

}

}`
Despite the success response, the app remains visible in the user's Klaviyo integrations list. Could you confirm whether additional steps are required to completely remove the app from the Klaviyo integrations page? If not, please advise on how to resolve this issue.
I tried sending latest refresh token as well as I tried by getting fresh access token and revoking it
